# Error using NP.savez and NP.load

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `data_list` and I save it as following:

```
    data_array = np.array(data_list)
    np.savez("File", data_array)
```

In order to load "File"

```
    a = np.load("File.npz") 
    b = a['arr_0']
```

I used this code until two weeks ago and it worked fine.
Today I have tried to work with my program, but it ends with a memory error identified in the line

```
   b = a['arr_0']
```

"File" has 300 MB dimension. So I don't think it's a memory problem.

Any idea about how it happened?

Comment: Could you show us the error?

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 241, in _getitem_
return format.read_array<value>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 459, in read_array
array = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=dtype,count=count)
Memory error

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What is the data you are storing? Do you get the same problem using a similarly shaped/sized np.randn?

Furthermore, it is probably useful to know that you can assign names to the arrays you store with np.savez by specifying them as kwargs, i.e.

```
np.savez("File", data_array=data_array)
```

then you can use

```
a = np.load("File.npz") 
b = a['data_array']
```

Also, note that (iirc) np.savez compresses files, so the problem might be due to the sheer size of your array, even if the resulting file is not so large.

Comment: Data I'm storing is a list containing 180 matrices 512x512.
If I save a list containing only one matrix there is not the problem.
How can I save and after load my list?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see your code, or preferably some minimal version of it that exhibits the unwanted behaviour.